# Connecting a Mavericks Mac to VPN using Forticlient

Tags: macos, networking, vpn

I´ve tried to connect to VPN using an account I was given, this account doesn´t have any shared secret, as fas as I know , they don´t provide any shared secret, their main argument is that my PC peers do connect without any problem using FortiClient, with only the gate, user and password for that purpose, I´ve been struggling really hard to connect to VPN, I downloaded FortiClient 5.0 and I just can´t connect, even when I ping the server (and all is Ok!), I just can´t connect, my PC peers do connect with no problems, and we all are behind a proxy, today I tried to connect from home, my initial thought was that the proxy was impeding a proper connection, but just the same, all I got was a -104 error, which I found is an error for a long connection name, in the office I just have nothing, no connection no nothing.

I´ve tried to onnect creating a VPN connection using the OS X itself (you can do it from the network preferences), I´ve tried using FortiClient for the Mac, I´ve tried using VPN tracker, and nothing happens, this last wednesday we did a test connecting an Ubuntu machine using my account and it all went Ok, my Mac is a recently bought Mac with Mavericks, so, no major additions or modifications have been made, any idea? o have you had a similar experience trying to connect a Mac to VPN in such conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Mac: Error-104 is caused by the software not having any kernel extensions enabled; to change this,
Boot into recovery mode, by restarting your laptop and holding Command+R when the laptop is in the power-off stage.
Once in recovery mode, on the top left, navigate to Utilities>Terminal.
With the terminal open type: spctl kext-consent add AH4XFXJ7DK

Write down part 3, you won't be able to access it from recovery mode.
Restart again, you should no longer have any issues once you log in. AH4XFXJ7DK is Forticlient's TeamID, you can google to double check.